# printing elements of tuple in different places

Tags: c#, tuples

Is there a way to print a single element in the tuple? Trying to print something like "The max value is " + max + " and it is located in the " + pos + " position."

```
public Tuple<int, int> find_oldie(int[] x)
{
     int max = x.Max();
     int pos = Array.IndexOf(x, max);
     return Tuple.Create(max, pos);
}
```

Comment: First of all, `Tuple<T1, T2>` doesn't allow you to name the members, they're named `Item1` and `Item2`, and higher arity tuples continue in that fashion. Additionally, you will have to use `tupleVariable.ItemX` to reach a particular member of the tuple, so you could do `... " + t.Item1 + " ... " + t.Item2 + "...`.

Comment: You can also use the new `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, which has more advanced syntactic sugar available through the compiler, in this way you could return `public (int max, int pos) find_oldie(...)`, which will also return a `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, and the compiler will apply some smoke and mirror effects to allow you to refer to the two members as `max` and `pos`. There is also additional "deconstruct" syntax that allows you to grab the values into distinct variables on the outside, which might get you closer to the exact syntax you want to achieve.

Comment: If you use the new ValueTuple type, you can declare your method as `public (int max, int pos) find_oldie(...)`, and you would return the value as `return (max, pos);`, then on the outside you could "deconstruct" this into two distinct variables with `(int max, int pos) = find_oldie(...)`. Other than the `...` parts here, the rest is verbatim how you would write the code. This, however, requires C# 7 or above (if I'm not mistaken), so depending on the version of things you're using it may or may not be available to you.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not a good duplicate choice for this question, although there may be others that are. The fact that he has named one of the tuple members "max" is nothing more than a name. It helps to read the question and not just trigger on a single word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Value.Tuple` to return `named` member of `Tuple`.

```
public (int Max, int Pos) find_oldie(int[] x)
{
    int max = x.Max();
    int pos = Array.IndexOf(x, max);
    return (max, pos);
}
```

@LasseV.Karlsen has already explained in detailed about `Value.Tuple` and ways to use it but I wanted to add that `deconstruct` can be used to create just one variable(which will have named members) So one can call above function as:

```
var val = ReturnNamedTupple();

Console.WriteLine($"The max value is {val.Max} and it is located in the {val.Pos}");
```